# LibreOffice 4.2.1.1: do not display list of recent documents

Tags: openoffice, history, libreoffice

Today I installed LibreOffice 4.2.1.1. When opening LO, it displays a list of recent documents with screenshots, similar to Firefox and Chrome. I don't want this. How can I disable this setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to disable the "PickList" / MRU:

- tweaking the config
- using an extension

### Tweaking the config:

1. Open the  LibreOffice config: Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Config`";
2. In the TreeView: "`LibreOffice`" -> "`Advanced`"
3. Button "`Expert Configuration`"
   [image]
4. In the preferences list, scroll down to preference "`/org.openoffice.Office.Common/History`"
5. Select the second property "`PickListSize`"
6. Click "`Edit`", set the value to "`0`"

Take care that this **won't clear the history / MRU**, it will just affect how much entries will be visible. If you increase the value after setting it to 0, the "old" history entries will appear again.

### Use the *History Master* extension

Check the [OpenOffice.org Extension "**History Master**"](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/HistoryMaster). It works for me like a charm in LibreOffice 4.2.0.4 and will allow to do some other nice things besides managing the PickList/MRU length.

Comment: Do you need to click "ok" on the "Expert Configuration" window or just close it? Having an issue - https://superuser.com/questions/1813133/cannot-scroll-down-to-click-okay-in-libreoffice-settings

Comment: @cardamom: yes, you need to click ok (or use ALT+O (O letter)) to confirm your setting.

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu that worked. No more recent documents..