# cannot scroll down to click okay in libreoffice settings

Tags: mouse, libreoffice, history, openoffice, window-manager

I tried to follow the instructions here -

[LibreOffice 4.2.1.1: do not display list of recent documents](https://superuser.com/questions/726467/libreoffice-4-2-1-1-do-not-display-list-of-recent-documents)

> Open the LibreOffice config: Menu "Tools" -> "Config";
> In the TreeView: "LibreOffice" -> "Advanced"
> Button "Expert Configuration"

...but I had to just close "Expert Configuration". Any attempt to resize the window to get to the "ok" button pushes the bottom of the window down and off the screen.

I'm running Debian Linux 11 with the Cinnamon desktop. Is this a problem with Libreoffice or somehow with the window manager and how can it be remedied?

Is there a keyboard shortcut to click the okay button for the situation where you can't get to it with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue, but i can offer a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (letter o) should do the same thing as clicking the OK button.

Comment: All I can think is the OP's screen resolution [or zoom factor] is below minimum spec for the app.